# Wordpress error on my website

Tags: php, wp-admin, customization, fatal-error

Hey guys I launched a recently built website for my client and everything seemed to be working fine, but recently whenever I try to edit anything, add a new page, delete something, etc. I get a fatal error. Anything regarding changing the website from the backend gives me a fatal error.

I've provided a screenshot of the error I get, and can provide login details if needed.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Not trying to be rude but no one is going to be able to help you without seeing some code and they would need access to your theme probably.  If you purchased this theme you should consult the creator.

Comment: Vader is right.  In this case, the error details presented are not pointing to the problem, unless you edited the WP core file listed.  Deactivate all plugins and try again.  If the error goes away, activate them one at a time.  If plugins are not the problem, change themes to isolate the issue.

Comment: It's not the theme. I talked to the theme developers and they switched it to another theme and the error still existed. I'll try the plugins one by one, but if that doesnt work what is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If none of this works I would suggest reinstalling WordPress. When you completed the site did you back it up? You could restore from a known good backup if you have one.